# C#'s Encoding.UTF8.GetString equivalent in Go

Tags: c#, go, utf-8

Whats the equivalent of C#'s Encoding.UTF8.GetString in Go?

As i already know that Go's default encoding is in UTF8 and string(somebytes) in Go would produce a UTF8 encoded string.

C#:

```
public static void Main()
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 144, 197, 217, 192, 204, 249, 181, 42, 92, 252, 243, 87, 170, 243, 169, 80, 175, 112, 192, 239};
    string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

    Console.WriteLine(str);
 }
```

Go:

```
func main() {
bytes := []byte { 144, 197, 217, 192, 204, 249, 181, 42, 92, 252, 243, 87, 170, 243, 169, 80, 175, 112, 192, 239}
str := string(bytes)
fmt.Println(str)
}
```

C# code produces:

```
�������*\��W��P�p��
```

Go code produces:

```
�������*\��W���P�p��
```

what I am missing here?

Comment: Your input byte sequence is not a valid UTF-8 byte sequence, yet you're attempting to treat it like that.

Comment: To expand on @icza's point: if you try to utf-8 decode something that isn't utf-8 input, then the output is undefined. It is perfectly reasonably to expect that two different frameworks will have different outcomes for an undefined scenario. Technically it is legal for a single framework to have a different outcome depending on the day of the week... it is, after all: *undefined*

Comment: Perhaps a more fruitful avenue to explore here is - *what are you trying to do?*: since that data isn't utf-8, clearly decoding it as utf-8 isn't a good option. Would displaying it as hex be useful to you?

Comment: @MarcGravell: "if you try to utf-8 decode something that isn't utf-8 input, then the output is undefined." Rob Pike, a co-author of UTF-8 and Go, returns the Unicode replacement character for invalid UTF-8 in Go. The output is well-defined, although it may not be useful.

Comment: @marc-gravell 
these bytes gets produced by the Hmac Sha1 algorithm, both c# and go produce same hash bytes as above. 
I have had this implementation working in c# where I convert those bytes to UTF8 string in one of my open source project. I am looking for the port to go.

Comment: @Kunal the output of a hmac sha hash is **not utf-8**. So... everything I said still applies. Indeed: hashes are almost always expressed as hex

Comment: @Kunal Might want to go back and modify that open source C# project then - it's clearly broken!

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, whatever way you look at it, your `bytes` are not valid UTF-8.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    bytes := []byte{144, 197, 217, 192, 204, 249, 181, 42, 92, 252, 243, 87, 170, 243, 169, 80, 175, 112, 192, 239}
    fmt.Println(len(bytes))
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", bytes)
    fmt.Printf("% x\n", bytes)
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", bytes)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", bytes)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/bHhkeGuZcCK

Output:

```
20
[144 197 217 192 204 249 181 42 92 252 243 87 170 243 169 80 175 112 192 239]
90 c5 d9 c0 cc f9 b5 2a 5c fc f3 57 aa f3 a9 50 af 70 c0 ef
"\x90\xc5\xd9\xc0\xcc\xf9\xb5*\\\xfc\xf3W\xaa\xf3\xa9P\xafp\xc0\xef"
�������*\��W���P�p��
```

References:

[The Unicode Consortium](http://www.unicode.org/)

[Unicode: UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 & BOM](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html)

[UTF-8 - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

[The Go Blog: Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://blog.golang.org/strings)

[Go: Package utf8](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/)